# Different actions on alert views buttons, depending on the alert view

Tags: iphone

I have 3 alert views in my apps. 
'wonAlert'
'lostAlert'
'nagAlert'

I implement this to give them actions.

```
 -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

This used to work fine, when I had just the 'wonAlert' and 'lostAlert', they had a dismiss and a learn more button that took them to wikipedia,
now I want the nag alert to take them to the app store.

how can I make it so the above method knows which alert view the tap is coming from, or something like that?

Cheers, Sam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you've got the UIAlertViews in variables, so I'd use them:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView == wonAlert) {
        //DO STUFF
    }
    else if (alertView == lostAlert) {
        //DO OTHER STUFF
    }
    else if (alertView == nagAlert) {
        //OPEN APP STORE
    }
}
```

More than one view can have the same tag and you can easily mistype the title or change it and forget to update the delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

In your view controller header file, add `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` so that it agrees to handle `UIAlertView` delegate methods:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> { ... }
```

In the implementation of your view controller, add the following delegate method:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)_actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)_buttonIndex {
    if ([_actionSheet.title isEqualToString:@"titleOfMyAlertView"]) {
        if (_buttonIndex == 0) {
            // do stuff for first button
        } 
        else if (_buttonIndex == 1) {
            // do something for second button
        }
        // etc. if needed
    }
}
```

The `_actionSheet.title` property can be used to distinguish between alert views. My recommendation is to use `NSString` constants or `NSLocalizedString()`, if you have a localized strings table, to title your alert views.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question here:
[Alert with 2 buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250299/alert-with-2-buttons/4250373#4250373)

the correct way to do this is using the tag property of alerts

upon creating each alert, set its tag variable by adding:

```
alertName.tag = #; //ex: alertName.tag = 1
```

Then, in the clickedButtonAtIndex method, you will need to add an 'if' block for each alert you have as shown in the folllowing code:

```
if(alert.tag == 1)
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        //do other stuff
    }
}
if(alert.tag == 2)
///...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do what Alex suggests, but use the tag property of the AlertView to determine which AlertView had been used.