# Alert with 2 buttons

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, alert

I'm going to have a link to a website in my app. The user will click on a button that says Website and an Alert will appear with 2 buttons. One of the buttons is just going to be a cancel button and the other button is going to open the website.

Could you help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Like lolcat said below, please specify what platform you're working with. Especially considering there are two completely different, yet correct, answers below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put this into your header file:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

put this into the class with your alert:

```
- (void)alertOKCancelAction {
  // open a alert with an OK and cancel button
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Open?" message:@"Open Website?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Open", nil];
  alert.tag = 1;
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
}
```

add this method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
  // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
  if(alert.tag == 1) 
  {
    if(buttonIndex == alert.cancelButtonIndex)
    {
      NSLog(@"cancel");
    }
    else
    {
      NSLog(@"ok");
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]]; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you are making an iphone app... based on your previous posting history. you should specify this when you post your questions though